# On monotonic quadratic least squares

Tags: statistics, quadratics, least-squares, monotone-functions

Quadratic least squares can be used to fit a quadratic curve to $3$ or more points, such that the resulting curve is the quadratic curve that has the least squared distance of the data points to the resulting curve.

Is there a way to do the same but with the restriction that the resulting curve is monotonic over a specific range? Like being monotonic in $[0,500]$ for instance.  The data set itself is monotonic over the same range.

One thing that's come to mind is to do a regular fit and then adjust the result to have positive derivatives.  While that would technically be a fit, I don't think it'd be optimal.

I've also thought about maybe doing some gradient descent to find a good fit, but I'm really hoping to find something like least squares, which is a constant time algorithm that doesn't get caught in local minima.

I specifically am trying to fit a monotonic quadratic curve to three data points, so any other technique that does the same would also be useful.

I'm looking to understand and implement this, so I'm looking for the information about how to do it, instead of being pointed at any software that might be able to do it for me.

Thank you!

Comment: A quadratic curve is a parabola, and none of those are monotonic. Maybe you have some different concept in mind – what do you really mean when you write, "monotonic"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson good point. I mean monotonic within a range. Updated the question.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo i could, and i'm betting the best fit curve does that, but how do i calculate where to put it, for the best fit?

Comment: @Rod, no, OP didn't mention the word, "restriction", but edited it in after my comment.

Comment: I don't see how you're going to get a good quadratic fit to the three pooints $(0,0),(1,3),(2,0)$ that's monotonic over $[0,500]$.

Comment: @Rod, of course I checked the edits. The "restriction" edit came two minutes after my comment.

Comment: @Rod, the problem currently states, "Is there a way to do the same but with the restriction that the resulting curve is monotonic over a specific range? Like being monotonic in [0,500] for instance."

Comment: @GerryMyerson the data set itself is monotonic over the same range. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: I'd suggest, Alan, that you go somewhere and have a good, long think about just exactly what it is that you actually want, and when you have decided that, then come back and post a good question.

Comment: I know what I want, but didn't mention details.  I've added them. I have 3 monotonic points, I want to fit it with a monotonic quadratic, ideally finding the best fit ala least squares.

Comment: Gerry, the resulting fit is often not monotonic. Please fix your attitude.

Comment: BTW, proof: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic+fit+(0,1),(1,2),(2,10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a set of points $\{ (x_i, y_i) \}_{i \in [n]}$ and would like to find a monotonic *segment* of a parabola that is "close" to them. Assuming that the parabola is of the following form $$y = a x^2 + b x + c$$ where $a \neq 0$, then the extremum is attained at $\bar x := -\frac{b}{2a}$. Hence, when solving the least-squares problem, append the inequality constraint

$$\bar x \leq \min_{i \in [n]} \{ x_i \}$$

or the the inequality constraint

$$\bar x \geq \max_{i \in [n]} \{ x_i \}$$

Try each of them and find which one yields the lowest least-squares "cost".

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply an inequality constraint to least squares. Is that something that can be explained easily?

Comment: Least-squares is an optimization problem. The nice, simple case has no constraints. In this case, we have an inequality constraint. This makes the optimization problem much harder. Fortunately, numerical optimization can handle these constraints. If you use Python, try [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org) (note that the code example on the main page is least-squares with inequality constraints).

Comment: Something simpler (but more restrictive) would be to replace the $\leq$ or $\geq$ with $=$. Handle the resulting equality constraint using, say, Lagrange multipliers. No need for numerical solvers.

Comment: I was specifically trying to avoid numerical methods, so thanks a bunch!

Comment: One more question: While this will give a fit, do you know if it will give the "best" (least squares) fit?

Comment: You have a convex quadratic program. Hence, if you find a minimizer, it should be unique and yield the global minimum. Whether you like the fit or not is another story. Assuming no mistakes, of course.

Comment: I have limited free time (two small kids) so haven't yet been able to implement it :)